# How to remove spaces from list value in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, removing-whitespace

I have a python list like

```
my_list = [' LCD | Autorotation',
 '  S o u n d  ',
 ' Power | No Power | AC Adapter Not Powering System',
 ' Motherboard',
 ' LCD | Lines on Display',
 '  W i r e l e s s  ',
 '  D N S   F a i l u r e',
 ' Power | Battery | Swollen']
```

There is a space between the characters of list values. What should be the best way to remove these spaces my output should look like below

```
my_list = [' LCD | Autorotation',
 '  Sound  ',
 ' Power | No Power | AC Adapter Not Powering System',
 ' Motherboard',
 ' LCD | Lines on Display',
 '  Wireless  ',
 '  DNS   Failure',
 ' Power | Battery | Swollen']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex to match spaces between single letters and replace them with nothing:

```
import re

new_list = [re.sub(r'(?<=\b\w) (?=\w\b)', '', item) for item in my_list]
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
[
 ' LCD | Autorotation',
 '  Sound  ',
 ' Power | No Power | AC Adapter Not Powering System',
 ' Motherboard',
 ' LCD | Lines on Display',
 '  Wireless  ',
 '  DNS   Failure',
 ' Power | Battery | Swollen'
]
```

Note: `\w` will also match digits and `_`. If that gives unintended results, just replace it with `[a-zA-Z]` in the regex i.e. `(?<=\b[a-zA-Z]) (?=[a-zA-Z]\b)`.